# Possible to pass name/value as parameter into Windows Console Application?

Tags: c#, console-application

Building one of my first console apps.

This console app will run some stored procedures I'm defining. I would like to be able to pass in parameter values via the command line.

Is there any way to pass in a name value pair? For example:

```
myConsoleApp.exe sproc_GetLastActives, @LastActiveDate - 11/20/2009
```

I know how to retreive the parameter values, but I'm noticing that the args[] are split if I put in a / or a ,. How can I pass in name value pair?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do you want that in a single string? Try this:

```
myConsoleApp.exe "sproc_GetLastActives, @LastActiveDate - 11/20/2009"
```

(i.e. just add quotes)

Slashes and commas shouldn't affect things, but the command line parser splits on spaces unless you've quoted it.

Answer (score 1):

There are several solutions to this problem the most common is to use '/' or '-' to prefix parameters and = to delimit them from their arguments for example

```
consoleapp.exe /spname=sproc_GetLastActives /LastActiveDate="11/20/2009"
```

in your code your code you can use String.Split(arg[i], new char[] {'='}) to bust up the individual parameters.

Answer (score 0):

`consoleapp.exe key1 val1 key2 val2`

`args[]` gives your 4 items, pair them up in your code. :P

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [mykhaylo's response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770589/possible-to-pass-name-value-as-parameter-into-windows-console-application/1770668#1770668), why not pass in the values at one string:

```
consoleapp.exe sproc_name key1=value1 "key2=Value With Spaces" key3=value3
```

Then just test for the presence of the `=` sign and parse it to get your key/value pair.